# Git: how to commit and cherry-pick bug fix?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

Our development team uses a `dev` branch for majority of commits and branch out each month for release branches. I was wondering what's the most popular model to handle bug fix commits. Commit to HEAD of `monthly` branch (most recent one, say `2015.Jun` branch) and cherry-pick (or just rebase) to `dev` branch? Or commit to HEAD of `dev` branch, then cherry-pick it to `monthly` branch. Which way is better?

According to this [site](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), it says "bugfixes from `rel.branch` may be continuously merged back into `dev` branch". Is this a good model? Are there any issues with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git-Flow (your link) or similar workflows are quite commonly used. Merging release branches back into develop regularly when bugfixes are applied is a good way to go IMHO.

About some other points in your question

> Commit to HEAD of monthly branch (most recent one, say 2015.Jun
>   branch) and cherry-pick (or just rebase) to dev branch?

You could cherry-pick them into develop but it wouldn't give an explicit "merge", visible in the history. As for rebasing the release branch onto develop, **you certainly don't want to do that**, as develop will have recent commits not stable and not related to the ongoing release. If you meant rebase develop onto release - although technically OK I would strongly avoid that as well so as to not rewrite any of the history of the develop, especially if there are multiple contributors.

> Or commit to HEAD of dev branch, then cherry-pick it to monthly
>   branch. Which way is better?

I don't recommend that either. If you're fixing a bug going into a release, it's very natural to fix it "in-place" in the release branch, and then merge release into develop to carry the fix over (or cherry-pick if you don't want to merge). Doing it the other way (fixing on develop and cherry-pick on release) doesn't guarantee that it will be compatible with the release.

To summarize my point of view, I would say it's best to be as explicit as possible. If you do a bugfix in the scope of a release, apply it on that branch then merge it to develop, where it may or may not result in a stable codebase.